# PulseAudio-alsa and X-server Issue Synchronization

Tags: linux-kernel, audio, pulseaudio, video

I use PulseAudio-Alsa (Arch x86_64, 5.7). Today I noticed a very weird issue and found 0 relevant issues online. It's really not too big of an issue, more than I'm blown away at the fact of what is happening. I will preface the problem with the equipment (The external devices probably do not matter but if you have an understanding of Linux internals, I believe you may be able to answer this question).

Studio Monitors: JBL LSR305

Audio: Pulseaudio-alsa

Video: X11 Server (i3-gaps) via `startx`

DAC: Focusrite Scarlett 2i2

---

Studio monitors naturally hiss; this is common and I am used to it. On Windows, the hiss is static and sounds the same no matter what I am doing (aka web browsing, gaming, making music, etc.). By this, I mean that the sound of the static does **not** change. It is the *same* static sound no matter the interaction (physically or via the monitor) .

Now on Linux, when I use my studio monitors (without a DAC), the static sound is different based on the current activity.. When I go to a website with a dark background, the static sound is just a bit different (enough for me to notice) than when I visit a website with a white background. Now, this sound is also **completely** different when I use vim or other applications (such as draw.io). The static sound is literally based on the video on my screen at the given moment. Not only this, but whenever I press a key on my keyboard, each key also generates an increased static sound, that is different for certain keys (the two key sounds that are different are ones that are physically farther away in the keyboard. This makes no sense to me.. In my dual boot windows install, using the same physical device (same keyboard, built-in monitor, jack port, etc.), the change in the static sound did **not** occur. So evidently, this is something unique to the Linux implementation (This is only my assumption. I have no proof to back up this claim).

Why is my keyboard driver and my video driver impacting my sound driver? Are these drivers somewhat synchronized at the kernel level?

This is not too big of a problem, as when I use my DAC, the change in the static sound does not occur. This makes sense, as this is an external audio device, managed by its own CPU, etc. I'd love to know why this is the case in Linux systems and if this is a bug or a 'feature'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're hearing the electrical noise produced by the operation of the various digital parts of the computer leaking into the audio output signal.

If this does not happen with Windows, that excludes the possibility of poor audio signal shielding within the motherboard. That is good, because the only way to fix poor internal shielding might be to use an external DAC.

Instead, it might be that the default settings of the ALSA driver enable monitoring for one or more audio inputs you aren't actively using, and the noise gets in through that. On a desktop computer, the microphone connector at the front of the chassis is a common cause of this problem, as it often has relatively long and possibly poorly-shielded wires inside the chassis, and needs to be sensitive for very weak signals.

When using Pulseaudio, running `alsamixer` without options may often show just the simplified mixer of Pulseaudio. Instead, you want the hardware mixing controls of ALSA, and you can get at them by adding the `-cN` option, where N is the number of the sound card whose mixer you wish to adjust. So if your computer has just one sound card or integrated sound chip, use `alsamixer -c0`. Then press <kbd>F4</kbd> for the capture channels, and ensure that the volume slider for any capture channel you are not actively using is fully down and the mute function is enabled, if applicable (use arrow keys for the sliders and the <kbd>M</kbd> key for the mute functionality, if present). This should minimize the noise leaking in.

Also, if the list of mixer channels includes "Loopback Mixing" or "What U Hear" (i.e. a signal path that allows you to record both microphone inputs and computer-generated audio at the same time) anywhere, try disabling it: it is known to be a noise-prone signal path in some sound chips.

Note that any audio input connector might have a volume slider on both "Capture" and "Playback" areas of the mixer: the former is for actual recording, while the latter is for "monitoring", i.e. feeding the microphone input directly to audio output for e.g. allowing you to hear your own voice when using a gaming headset. Again, if you are not actively using an input channel, you'll want the volume slider for its "Playback" channel fully down and the mute function enabled, if available.